# Xcode cpu gauge custom data

Tags: ios, xcode

working in a small team and I’m noticing that some of the team has additional data points in the CPU gauge section of Xcode.  I’m not seeing an option for it, is this some plugin/custom script?  They believe it is native in Xcode but no one can find the option...

Image with average and cap:

[image: View image with average and cap]

Image with no cap or average legend/data:

[image: View Image with no cap or average legend/data]

Comment: It would probably help if you specified which data you are talking about (with a screenshot of the two situations for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cap and average on the "Usage over Time" graph in Xcode's "CPU Report" are for watchOS 3 "background running" for which the average CPU usage must fall below a certain "cap" (or else watchOS may suspend your app). I'm assuming your first screen snapshot is a watchOS process, whereas your latter image is not.

WWDC 2016 videos [What's New in watchOS 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/208/) and [Building Great Workout Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/235/).

Comment: Thank you for your response